# Update a database continuously

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am a newbie in software development, building an Angular TS app that manages people in a queue and I use Firebase/Firestore for my back-end. There are 3 status for a user: the user is either waiting, called or out of the queue. When a user is called, he/she has to respond "present" before 10s, otherwise he/she is automatically put out of the queue.

I try to implement this last specification by activating at each second a service that will check if the time limit has been exceeded and will update in that case the user status to 'out of the queue' in its corresponding firestore document.

**user.service.ts**

```
 unqueueUser(): any {
 const actualTime = new Date();

 this.afs.collection<User>('users', ref =>
 ref.orderBy('status.call_moment.time_lim', 'asc')
   .where('status.value', '==', "CALLED")
   .where('status.call_moment.time_lim', '<=', actualTime))
   .snapshotChanges()
   .pipe(map((actions: DocumentChangeAction<User>[]) => {
      const indices = [];
      actions.map((a: DocumentChangeAction<User>) => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        indices.push(data.id);
      });
      return indices;
    }))
    .subscribe(data => {
      for (const id of data) {
        return this.afs.doc(`users/${id}`)
        .update({
          'status.value': "OUT OF THE LINE",
        });
      }
    });
 }
```

**user.component.ts**

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
userList: User[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getUserList().subscribe(data => this.userList = data);

  setInterval(() => { this.userService.unqueueUser(); }, 1000);
 }
}
```

The biggest issue in my solution is that it's easy to reach the limit of read operations at half of a day (and I got a hundred of users to handle !).

Do you know a better solution? Lemme know if you need further info to sort it out. Thanks !

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: Part of the beauty of Firebase is it's a 'live' database and provides real time events. This should be fairly straight forward; each user adds an observer to their 'status' node. When it changes, your app will receive an event (containing the new status). Start a 10s timer on the device and if they do not respond within that timeframe, remove them from the queue. But, we need to see some code and perhaps a more clear explanation of the issue. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i edited the post.

Comment: @Jay Can you provide me with a piece of code that implements the listener and the 10s timer on the device you are talking about?

Comment: Now that you know what to do 1) Add an observer to a node ($watch(callback, context) in AngularFire) and 2) create a timer, you have the direction. Attempt to write some code for those two tasks and when you get stuck, post a question and we'll take a look!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of polling each second for 10 seconds, just read at the end of the 10 if there was a response, you should get 10 times as many reads that way.  If you need it to be a bit more responsive than that, only poll every 5 seconds.

Comment: Yeah this is good if you only have a single user to manage but not all the users will be called at the same time, so the solution should be able to handle that time disparities